# Delphi TDataSet filter case insensitive not working

Tags: delphi, dataset, delphi-2006

I have an application with lots of datasets created at run-time. Some of this datasets are filtered. As filterOptions I've set foCaseInsensitive

```
dataset.FilterOptions := [foCaseInsensitive];
```

that means that '[foCaseInsensitive  - Ignore case when comparing strings.](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Setting_Filter_Options) ' according to Delphi help.

The `dataset.filter` is changed on user input.

At begging it shows all values:

[image]

when user type something is changed:

[image]

The problem is that when I'm typing the last character, it shows nothing

[image]

Problem does not appear when I'm typing on upper-case

[image]

how can I fix this, to show correct the values when user input is only in lower case?

LE: the component is a standard [TDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSet) from Delphi. 
Filter is assigned with 'Like %value_entered%'.

LE1: I'm using a in-house component which has a DataSet property. After I'm setting the filter, I set the property Filtered to true. So, it is a TDataSet property on what I'm talking about.

Comment: what DataSet type are you using and how do you construct the filter?

Comment: as a work-around I can set the filter by adding what user types upper-cased. This 'solves' the problem...It is this problem known?

Comment: I'm with kobik, we need to knwo what TDataset descendant you're using.

Comment: As I wrote in the LE is the TDataSet class from Delphi - http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DB.TDataSet

Comment: for example: if the TDataSet is TADODataSet you should use the TADODataSet(DataSet).Filter. no need to set FilterOptions. plus on SQLServer and Oracle you should add N'%value_entered%' if the field is ntext.

Comment: You are not using a TDataSet, you're using a TDataSet descendant. A TDataSet does nothing when you change the filter text except for setting 'FFilterText'.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - yes, you are right. I'm also set the filtered property to true. I will edit the question.

Comment: @RBA - What I meant was a TDataSet descendant *have* to override SetFilteredText and SetFiltered to make any useful work. Otherwise nothing will happen. Your component *have* to be instantiating a descendant class, despite the property being a TDataSet.

Comment: do this: `ShowMessage(DataSet.ClassName);` and write here what is the output. also put the code of the TEdit OnChange event.

Comment: Did you apply D2006 update packs? That release was really buggy.